# Entity Framework Count causes TSQL subquery

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have a simple EntityFramework application that accesses SQL Server 08 with a single table. I want to get a count of the rows like this:

```
Dim x = (From y in _Ctx.Table1).Count
```

Here's the SQL generated from this EF:

```
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[Table1] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Question: Is there a way to have EF generate simpler SQL without the subquery, e.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table1
```

Thanks in advance,
david

Answer (score 1):

No.

And: it doesn't matter.

Comment: Agreed.  Although it is wordier, SQL Server doesn't care.  It will parse it into the same plan.  If you really like simple SQL code, don't use EF.  (Just wait until you see it auto-gen complex queries!)